# How to set all descendant nodes and links to same colour as level 2 ancestor?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3.js tree with descendant nodes receiving their level 2 ancestor's node colour.  This is working from level 2 to level 3, but stops working at level 4 and on.

[image]

Relevant code:

```
var colourScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["MD","Professional", "Leader", "Advocate", "Clinician", "Educator", "Scholar"])
    .range(["#6695c8", "#cd3838","#d48440", "#a8ba5f", "#63b7c0", "#c97eb2", "#ccc136"]);
```

and

```
 nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill-opacity","0.7")
    .attr("stroke-opacity","1")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.depth === 2 ? colourScale(d.parent.name) : colourScale(d.name);
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.depth === 2 ? colourScale(d.parent.name) : colourScale(d.name);
    });
```

and

```
// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return 1;
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .attr("opacity","0.3")
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return d.target.depth === 2 ? colourScale(d.target.parent.name) : colourScale(d.target.name);
    });
```

How can I set ALL descendants of a parent to the same colour (nodes and links)?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rensh6p4/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a recursive function to go up the hierarchy until you find a node with the correct `depth`. For instance:

```
function findParent(datum) {
  if (datum.depth < 2) {
    return datum.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.parent)
  }
}
```

Or even shorter with a ternary:

```
function findParent(datum) {
    return datum.depth < 2 ? datum.name : findParent(datum.parent);
};
```

Then, you can pass it to the colour scale:

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
    return colourScale(findParent(d));
})
```

Here is the updated code:

```js
var treeData = [{
  "name": "MD",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Professional",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third A",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Fourth A",
        "children": [{
          "name": "Fifth A"
        }, {
          "name": "Fifth B"
        }, {
          "name": "Fifth C"
        }, {
          "name": "Fifth D"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Fourth B"
      }, {
        "name": "Fourth C"
      }, {
        "name": "Fourth D"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Third B"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Leader",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third C"
    }, {
      "name": "Third D"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Advocate",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third E"
    }, {
      "name": "Third F"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Clinician",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Third G"
    }, {
      "name": "Third H"
    }, ]
  }, ]
}];



var colourScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["MD", "Professional", "Leader", "Advocate", "Clinician"])
  .range(["#6695c8", "#cd3838", "#d48440", "#a8ba5f", "#63b7c0"]);


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 1200 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 650 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");


// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);



// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {


  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);



  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 200;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "#C0C0C0" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill-opacity", "0.7")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", "1")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colourScale(findParent(d));
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return colourScale(findParent(d));
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return 1;
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .attr("opacity", "0.3")
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return colourScale(findParentLinks(d));
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

function findParent(datum) {
  if (datum.depth < 2) {
    return datum.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.parent)
  }
}

function findParentLinks(datum) {
  if (datum.target.depth < 2) {
    return datum.target.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.target.parent)
  }
}


// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);

}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #C0C0C0;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 yes, the properties `depth` and `parent` still exist in v5.

Comment: Ok, then something else has broken this after migrating to v5.... I will ask a new question.