# Color descendant nodes and links broken after moving to d3 v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I had the [colouring of decendant nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322693/how-to-set-all-descendant-nodes-and-links-to-same-colour-as-level-2-ancestor) and links working in my tree in d3.js v3.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdv7wLb8/1/)

After migration to v5, this has broken, not sure why.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdv7wLb8)

V5 code:

```
var colourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["MD", "Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3", "Year 4"])
    .range(["#abacab", "#53e28c", "#4b80fa", "#eab014", "#bd57fe"]);
```

and

```
function findParent(datum) {
    if (datum.depth < 2) {
        return datum.name
    } else {
        return findParent(datum.parent)
    }
}

function findParentLinks(datum) {
    if (datum.target.depth < 2) {
        return datum.target.name
    } else {
        return findParent(datum.target.parent)
    }
}
```

and

```
// Update the node attributes and style
nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 7)
    .attr("fill-opacity", "0.7")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", "1")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.class === "found") {
            return "#ff4136"; //red
        } else {
            return (typeof d._children !== 'undefined') ? (colourScale(findParent(d))) : '#FFF';
        }
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
        if (d.class === "found") {
            return "#ff4136"; //red
        } else {
            return colourScale(findParent(d));
        }
    });
```

...

```
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
            return 1;
        })
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {
                x: source.x0,
                y: source.y0
            };
            return diagonal({
                source: o,
                target: o
            });
        })
        .attr("opacity", "0.3")
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return colourScale(findParentLinks(d));
        });

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3 v5 the property you're looking for (`name`) is inside an object called `data`, which is automatically created by the hierarchy generator.

Therefore, it should be:

```
function findParent(datum) {
  if (datum.depth < 2) {
    return datum.data.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.parent)
  }
}
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5uc2g9sw/

Comment: Thanks again.  The links aren't being coloured, but that is because I have not added the findParentLinks() code to the link code in the fiddle.  Still, testing just now, the links aren't working properly with that code added.  May be a new question..

Comment: Ah, just used the following for links and works fine: .style( "stroke", function ( d ) {
      return colourScale( findParent( d ) );
     } );